# C++ shared_from_this() is not letting obj get destructed

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

I have a following piece of code, which is creating a simple object of Name and inside that it is creating another object Name, with a `shared_from_this()` reference. As I am reading from here
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

*"Effectively executes std::shared_ptr(weak_this), where weak_this is the private mutable std::weak_ptr member of enable_shared_from_this."*

Which I am understanding as shared_from_this() is only creating a weak pointer to shared obj. But I don't see this is the case in runtime. There is effectively a circular reference getting created.

At the end of the I was expecting the Name obj should be destructed, but it is not because the reference counter is 2.

Can someone help me understand how should I use `enable_shared_from_this()`, that can effectively cleanup the Name obj, once it goes out of reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct Another;
struct Name : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Name> {
    std::string t;
    int m, n, p;
    shared_ptr<Another> ann;
    Name() {
        std::cout << "constructor\n";
    }
    void MakeSomething() {
        ann = std::make_shared<Another>(shared_from_this());
    }
    ~Name() {
        std::cout << "destructor\n";
    }
};

struct Another {
    shared_ptr<Name> nn;
    Another(shared_ptr<Name> n) : nn(n) {
        std::cout << "from another constructor " << nn.use_count() << "\n";
    }
    ~Another() {
        std::cout << "from another destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto n = std::make_shared<Name>();
        std::cout << "Name ref count so far: " << n.use_count() << "\n";

        auto p = n.get();
        //delete p;
        std::cout << "Name ref count so far: " << n.use_count() << "\n";

        n->MakeSomething();
        std::cout << "Name ref count so far: " << n.use_count() << "\n";
        {
            shared_ptr<Name> m = n;
            std::cout << "Name ref count so far: " << n.use_count() << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "Name ref count so far: " << n.use_count() << "\n";
    }
    // problem: at this point Name obj, should go out of reference and destructor to be called, which is NOT happening

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the runtime output (compiler used msvc)

```
constructor
Name ref count so far: 1
Name ref count so far: 1
from another constructor 3
Name ref count so far: 2
Name ref count so far: 3
Name ref count so far: 2
```

Comment: You have a circular reference of shared_ptrs. They never go out of scope, because they point to each other.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, I am aware of it. `shared_from_this` is creating the circular reference, when in documentation it is saying it is creating a weak reference. What should be the correct way to use `shared_from_this`

Comment: You probably need to have one of them use a std::weak_ptr

Comment: It has nothing to do with `shared_from_this`. You have two `shared_ptr`s, both point to each other. They cannot release on their own, because there is never a moment when either ends its lifetime. You would need to release (`reset()`) one of them manually to break the circle. Or one of them must not be a `shared_ptr`, but a `weak_ptr` or a raw, non-owning pointer.

Comment: *"`shared_from_this` is creating the circular reference"* -- no, it is *you* who created the circular reference. If the function `shared_from_this` is called in isolation (not assigned to something), it returns a temporary object that is immediately destroyed. It takes your `ann` and `nn` members to create the circular reference. All `shared_from_this` did was simplify the code that creates the circular reference; it is not an essential part of that code.

Comment: I'm debating the wisdom of posting an answer to this. It might be worth answering if this is likely to be a widespread misreading of the documentation. Could you explain how you read *"executes std::shared_ptr(weak_this)"*, which means executing the constructor of `shared_ptr`, and concluded *"only creating a weak pointer"*?

Comment: I am sorry,  I completely misunderstood this. `weak_ptr` does what i am looking.

Answer (score 0):

> Which I am understanding as shared_from_this() is only creating a weak pointer to shared obj. But I don't see this is the case in runtime. There is effectively a circular reference getting created.

`shared_from_this()` is creating a `weak_ptr`, which you're passing to a `shared_ptr` constructor, as specified by (11) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). That constructor creates a `shared_ptr` to the same object, increasing the reference count.

Also keep in mind that `weak_ptr` does not contribute to the reference count at all, so it has no bearing on your confusion over the reference count. Focus on what the `shared_ptr`s are doing.

Comment: `shared_from_this()` creates a `std::shared_ptr` while `weak_from_this()` creates a `std::weak_ptr()`. Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this